# Python group same items with different names

Tags: python

A folder contains(around 5000) .json files with different names, but the data in them might be the same. I have checked for the data and found the files with same data. The result looks like:

```
    jsonfile0 = jsonfile1
    jsonfile3 = jsonfile4
    jsonfile3 = jsonfile5
    jsonfile4 = jsonfile5
```

and so on

I need to group the files as (jsonfile0,jsonfile1) (jsonfile3, jsonfile4, jsonfile5) and so on. Apart from itertools is there any other way to compare files as itertools is time consuming.

Below given is my code till now.

```
x = 'File_Directory'
def compare_values(obj):
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    return sorted((k, compare_values(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
if isinstance(obj, list):
    return sorted(compare_values(x) for x in obj)
else:
    return obj

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("%s" % x):
for y in files:
    if y.endswith('.json'):
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(files, 2):
            a = a.encode('ascii')
            b = b.encode('ascii')
            with open('%s/%s' % (x,a)) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            with open('%s/%s' %(x, b)) as af:
                adata = json.load(af)
            if compare_values(data) == compare_values(adata):
                print a, '=', b
```

**Kindly note: Python version = 2.7.14, Operating System = Windows 7

Comment: If your goal is to produce groups of identical files, why do you use this inefficient intermediate step of generating these much larger lists of `jsonfilexx = jsonfileyy`?

Comment: oh that was just to ensure whether my code was working in the desired manner :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a hash function such as `binascii.crc32` to calculate a practically unique hash for each unique file content, and then use a dict of lists to group files by their hashes:

```
from binascii import crc32
import os

groups = {}
for root, _, files in os.walk('File_Directory'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.json'):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                groups.setdefault(crc32(f.read()), []).append(path)
```

so that:

```
print([l for l in groups.values() if len(l) > 1])
```

will output all the duplicating files in grouped sub-lists.